# How to make both panels aligned regardless of height?

Tags: html, css

I have two panels:

[image: panels]

They are aligned perfectly. Now, let us say I add text in panel 1 which changes it's height.

It is no longer aligned:

[image: text added to panel 1]

I'm not sure how to fix this or why it is happening. How can I keep both panels aligned regardless what I add to them?

I created a JSFiddle to make it easy to edit: 
https://jsfiddle.net/8qafwy93/7/

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="panel">
    <h1>Panel 1</h1>
    <p>Remove this</p>
  </div>

  <div class="panel">
    <h1>Panel 2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  background: slategray;
}

.row{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.panel{
  background: white;
  width: 49%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use flexboxes

You add:

```
.row{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

This will turn your roll div into a flex contianer and with `justify-content` you add some space between elements;

If you want to know more about flexboxes i recommend

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)
[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Hope this helps :)

```css
body{
  background: slategray;
}

.row{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.panel{
  background: white;
  width: 49%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="panel">
    <h1>Panel 1</h1>
    <p>Remove this</p>
  </div>
 
  <div class="panel">
    <h1>Panel 2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using inline-block to horizontally align your elements, uou could add the following code to your panel rule:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

The vertical-align property allow you to specify the vertical alignment of inline inside there inline formatting context.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align